# Python BreathFirstSearch -pathing problem

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

This is my first post here, I am a python beginner working on a project for school.

My specific problem is a part of the berkeley pacman project1: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/sp19/project1.html

**On the BFS part I am running into trouble. specifically on the tinyMap while my program is in 2,2 state it transitions to 2,3 normally but 2,1 has an extra north direction.**

successorsVisited is a set of coordinate states
myQueue is a regular queue
problem is the board
getSuccessors returns a list of Tuples (state, direction, cost) which i edit into (state, direction, cost, path) before pushing it back into the queue.

please assume I have handled the base case correctly this is the iteration step starting with 5,4 and 4,5 in the queue.

```
def BFS_Helper(problem,myQueue,successorsVisited):
    while not myQueue.isEmpty():
        node = myQueue.pop()
        state = node[0]
        for x in range(0,len(problem.getSuccessors(state))):
            aTuple = problem.getSuccessors(state)[x]
            if aTuple[0] not in successorsVisited:
                successorsVisited.add(aTuple[0])
                node[3].append(aTuple[1])
                bTuple = (aTuple[0], aTuple[1], aTuple[2],  node[3]) # new bTuple with path = path + action 
                print(bTuple)
                if problem.isGoalState(aTuple[0]):
                    return bTuple[3]
                myQueue.push(bTuple)
    return BFS_Helper(problem, myQueue,successorsVisited)
```

i print out a bTuple before checking the goal state here is the print out. the north that is bolded is my problem, i cannot figure out how it happened.

((5, 3), 'South', 1, ['South', 'South'])

((3, 5), 'West', 1, ['West', 'West'])

((4, 3), 'West', 1, ['South', 'South', 'West'])

((2, 5), 'West', 1, ['West', 'West', 'West'])

((4, 2), 'South', 1, ['South', 'South', 'West', 'South'])

((1, 5), 'West', 1, ['West', 'West', 'West', 'West'])

((3, 2), 'West', 1, ['South', 'South', 'West', 'South', 'West'])

((1, 4), 'South', 1, ['West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'South'])

((2, 2), 'West', 1, ['South', 'South', 'West', 'South', 'West', 'West'])

((1, 3), 'South', 1, ['West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'South', 'South'])

((2, 3), 'North', 1, ['South', 'South', 'West', 'South', 'West', 'West', 'North'])

((2, 1), 'South', 1, ['South', 'South', 'West', 'South', 'West', 'West', **'North'**, 'South'])

((1, 1), 'West', 1, ['South', 'South', 'West', 'South', 'West', 'West', 'North', 'South', 'West'])

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your problem is here:

```
node[3].append(aTuple[1])
```

This will become an issue when the loop over the successors has more iterations. In those iterations the *same* `node[3]` is used... which still has the appended value in it from a previous iteration, and you add *yet another* value to it.

Solution: don't mutate `node[3]`. Instead, create a new list on-the-fly:

```
bTuple = (aTuple[0], aTuple[1], aTuple[2],  node[3] + [aTuple[1]])
```

Comment: thank you very much! do the operator overloads always generate a new non mutated variable in python? when searching myself I kept finding that python didn't really have by reference or by value.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, in Python, methods that *return* the result, do not mutate the operand (like `copy`, `+`). Methods or operators that do *not* return the result (but `None`) will mutate the operand (like `append`, `extend`, `sort`, `+=`...). This has little to do with call-by-reference or by-value. That concept is about how functions deal with their arguments. In Python there is no call-by-reference: when you *assign* a new value to a function argument, the caller's variable is not affected.